# Example Needed of Phonegap Sqlite Insert record and then insert other records into a different table

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have it a point that has really got me stuck and help is need

I have two tables 
1) Jobs
2) JobNotes

Jobs is made up like the following
ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
Name nvarchar(100) COLLATE NOCASE
etc..

JobNotes is made up like the following
ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
JobID integer .
Notes nvarchar(100) COLLATE NOCASE
FOREIGN KEY ([JobID ])        REFERENCES Jobs,

When i insert a job into the database I need to insert the jobnote and set the JobID to be the id of the job just inserted previously.

Has anyone got examples or know of a method this can be accomplished using phonegap & sqlite.

Best Regards,
Lmac

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing the insert I get the max id and then pass this into another function that updates the Foreign key.

Its not the most desired way but so far seems to work.